# Algorithmically convert a sequence of pathname inclusion/exclusion rules to a find command?

Tags: algorithm, find

Consider an arbitrary sequence of pathname prefix inclusion/exclusion rules interpreted using the following metarules:

- precondition: rules pertaining to a directory will follow any rules pertaining to its ancestors
- subsequent rules override previous rules, .gitignore style

or in pseudocode:

```
for each pathname in `find .`

    pathname.excluded = true //or false - two variants of the problem

    for each rule in rules
        if pathname.starts_with(rule)
            pathname.excluded = rule.is_exclusion

    if !pathname.excluded
        output pathname
```

I am looking for an algorithm that would convert such a specification to the format required by the find command, i.e. alternating -prunes and -prints.

find . `stuff` -prune -o `stuff` -print -o `...`

The output of such a find command should be set-identical to the output of the above pseudocode algorithm.

The difficulty here is that with the find command once a directory is -pruned, it cannot be unpruned and find won't even recurse into it, so subsequent "inclusion rules" pertaining to its descendants will have no effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make a trie where each node has a boolean field `excluded`. For each rule in order, insert it into the trie as follows. Walk down to its node in the trie, creating new nodes with `excluded` equal to the default exclusion as necessary. At that node, delete its children.

The meaning of the trie is, to determine whether a path is excluded, walk in the trie according to the path as long as possible, then return the `excluded` value for the last node reached.

To translate the trie into a `find` command, specify a rule for each of its nodes. External nodes yield prefix matches. Internal nodes yield exact matches.